# How to see child Activity from its ancestor, in Android Java Programming?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I know this question does not make great sense, but somehow I think that its not impossible.

I have defined a "base" class, where all the other activities extend it. Like this:

```
public class ExtendedActivity extends Activity 
{
}

public class Activity1 extends ExtendedActivity
{
}

public class Activity2 extends ExtendedActivity
{
}
```

So I need to call a method in `ExtendedActivity` 's `onCreate` method, only if the current Activity is not `Activity1`

How can I manage that ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: call a method from where? maybe explain with an example..

Comment: @Amulya Khare sorry, I meant onCreate method. added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have classes as follows:

```
public class ExtendedActivity extends Activity 
{
    protected void method1() {
    }
}

public class Activity1 extends ExtendedActivity
{

}

public class Activity2 extends ExtendedActivity
{
}
```

You can call `method1()` only if `currentActivity` is **NOT** `Activity1` as follows:

```
 Activity currentActivity = this;   
 if(!(currentActivity instanceof Activity1)) {
        currentActivity.method1();
 }
```

Comment: Yes this is what I'm looking for. But no, I don't know how to get the current activity :)

Comment: Thanks! it works. But I'm recognizing I have asked the question a little bit wrong. I need to call `method1()` , after the child's `onCreate` has called `setContentView()`. any ideas for that ? Should I put the code in `onResume()` of `ExtendedActivity`?

Comment: just call it after the line where you `setContentView()`? Why is this a problem?

Comment: the problem is `setContentView` is called (in the child) after `super.onCreate()` has been finished. But putting your code into `onResume` of parent, worked. Thanks for your help :)